# How can I using custom JSX coexistence with React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

We have implemented a set of JSX syntax ourselves. In order to use ecology such as JSX syntax highlighting, we define our file suffix as .x.tsx

We wrote our own loader, but in the case of coexistence with React, our JSX syntax will report a lot of errors.

[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbdZQ.png)

I don't know if there is a way to distinguish .x.tsx and .tsx

Any Ideas?

Code:

```js
// XComponent.x.tsx

import X, { InnerComponentA } from 'xReact';

export default () => <InnerComponentA style={{ componentHeight: 100 }} />;
```

```js
// XRender.x.tsx

import { render } from 'xReactDOM';
import XComponent from './XComponent.x';

export default (container: HTMLElement) => render(container, XComponent);
```

```js
// ReactComponent.tsx

import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import renderX from './XRender.x';

export default () => {
  const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    renderX(divRef.current);
  }, []);

  return <div ref={divRef} />
}
```

Comment: costomeComponent.jsx

const costomeComponent = ()=>{

}

export default costomeComponent;

One.jsx
import costomeComponent from "costomeComponent"
const One = ()=>{

</costomeComponent>
}

export default One;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a TS plugin to block React JSX errors on .x.tsx files. Now the prompt is also complete and perfect.

refs:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Architectural-Overview
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API